# Scaling a canvas to full screen really decreases the resolution

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a full screen game to help me learn JS.  I made a canvas item and streched it to the size of the screen using CSS.  Then I draw a circle.  The issue I have is that the circle looks terrible!

```
_draw.arc(20, 20, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
```

Here is a jsfiddle example.  http://jsfiddle.net/H5dHD/152/

I've tried using different scale factors (so _draw.scale) but it dosent seem to matter...

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.  I know the coordinates are off.  I didn't include that code for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you resized the canvas using the CSS-style, and do not change the actual width and height. When you use CSS styling to change the size, the canvas will be stretched, but the internal drawing resolution stays the same. The result is that the canvas blurs.

To change the internal resolution, change the width and height attributes of the canvas HTML element itself.

```
document.getElementById('iDraw').height = screen.availHeight;
document.getElementById('iDraw').width = screen.availWidth;
```

Here is your updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/H5dHD/154/

Comment: [Slaps forehead with hand]

Comment: @Dave It's a typical mistake which almost all beginners make.